# Passing multiple arguments to curried functions

Tags: javascript, function, arguments, closures, currying

I'm currently reading the book, *Effective Javascript* and have reached the chapter regarding closures. There's an example that illustrates how to pass  the argument of a nested function as so:

```
function sandwichMaker(magicIngredient) {
  function make(filling) {
    return magicIngredient + " and " + filling;
  }

  return make;
}

var hamAnd = sandwichMaker("ham");

hamAnd("swiss"); // ham and swiss
```

But if I were to pass two arguments (one for the initial function, the second for the nested function) I get undefined for the second parameter:

```
sandwichMaker("ham", "swiss"); // ham and undefined
```

Do I always need to declare a variable first then provide the second argument once I want to invoke it?

Comment: `sandwichMaker("ham")("swiss");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `sandwichMaker` returns a function, the actual call that you're looking for is `sandwichMaker("ham")("swiss");`

Remember that without the parentheses following the name, a function will behave just like any other variable in that you can pass it around without actually evaluating or "running" it.

So, `return make;` gives you a function that you can evaluate at a later time, while `return make(...);` gives you the value of evaluating `make`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass a parameter to the second function without storing it in a variable you can do it like this

```
sandwichMaker("ham")("swiss");
```